# How to resolve "ListenAndServe error: listen tcp 10.10.1.1:8080: bind: cannot assign request address"

Tags: go, http

I am trying to write an api based on existing api. So it means, we have `http://api.stackoverflow.11.io:8080` and `/askQuestions`, but it needs a lot of authentication part to call `http://api.stackoverflow.11.io:8080/askQuestions`. I am creating a new project to write the authentication part into the `questionsHandler` function. So that we can call `http://api.stackoverflow.11.io:8080/askQuestions` without authentication.

Currently, `http://api.stackoverflow.11.io:8080` api is running in a pod and podIP is 10.10.1.1, so how can I start a new project and write the route function in Golang? Thanks!

```
func main() {
    u, err := url.Parse("http://api.stackoverflow.11.io:8080")
    if err != nil {fmt.Println(err)}
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/askQuestions", questionsHandler)

    err = http.ListenAndServe(u.Host, mux)
    if err != nil {fmt.Println(err)}
}
```

I tried to 1. change the address to http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:8080", r)
2. use reverseProxy and change port number
3. change the port number to url.Parse("http://api.stackoverflow.11.io:8081")
but failed

Comment: Why don't you use `http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux)`? Why do you want to supply a hostname here?

Comment: You can't listen on a domain name, only on an interface/IP and port.

Answer (score 0):

As Adrian pointed out, you cannot listen to a domain name.
Let's look at the documentation for

```golang
// ListenAndServe listens on the TCP network address addr and 
// then calls Serve with handler to handle requests on incoming connections.
// Accepted connections are configured to enable TCP keep-alives.
func ListenAndServe(addr string, handler Handler) error
```

Does probably not tell you much, but at least it hints that you should use a TCP network address (a 32bit number).

An IP address is a 32-bit number. It uniquely identifies a host (computer or another device, such as a printer or router) on a TCP/IP network.

---

If you want to route the traffic to different pods based on the endpoint you'd probably need some sort of proxy.
One great tool for this could be [treafik](https://traefik.io/)